# Oracle SQL Sysdate not comparing properly with nls_date_format='DD-MON-RR'

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a oracle sql code that is getting an inconsistent result when using sysdate compared to the manually entered dates (for last thursdays or fridays).

Ex:

1. Alter session set nls_date_format='DD-MON-RR';
2. query with the following where clause that runs custom dates on **Mondays**:

   **Manual entry that works correctly:**

   ```
   WHERE DATECOLUMN= to_date('2021/01/29','yyyy/mm/dd') -- key in previous Friday's date

   WHERE DATECOLUMN= case when to_char(sysdate,'D')=2 then sysdate-3 
                          else to_date('9999/01/01','yyyy/mm/dd') 
                     end -- if today is monday, then pick last Friday's date for the run else pick a dummy date.
   ```

I am certain the alter session script in python is working correctly since I tested in Alteryx as well. However, I am still having trouble getting the result to match for manually entered dates. I tested the comparison of sysdate-3 vs. DATECOLUMN using select and it seems to be working on TOAD so I am not seeing the issue causing a mismatch.

What could be the cause of such a mismatch in results when both pieces of code are supposed to compare the DATECOLUMN with the same value?

Answer (score 1):

The result of `to_char(sysdate,'D')` depends on current user sessions `NLS_TERRITORY` settings.

For more reliable solution better use for example:

```
TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'fmDay', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') = 'Monday'
```

Answer (score 0):

`SYSDATE - 3` returns both DATE **and** TIME components, e.g.

```
SQL> select sysdate - 3 from dual;

SYSDATE-3
-------------------
05.02.2021 11:06:04

SQL>
```

Your code suggests that `DATECOLUMN` contains only DATE component. Therefore, try with

```
trunc(sysdate) - 3
```

which will "remove" time component (actually, will set value to previous midnight):

```
SQL> select trunc(sysdate) - 3 from dual;

TRUNC(SYSDATE)-3
-------------------
05.02.2021 00:00:00
```

So, your code would then be

```
WHERE DATECOLUMN= case when to_char(sysdate,'D')=2 then trunc(sysdate) - 3 
                       else to_date('9999/01/01','yyyy/mm/dd') 
                  end
```